# Go Reflection Panic: Call using interface{} as type

Tags: go, reflection, interface, call, panic

I was tinkering with reflection in Go, and I came across an interesting scenario. `call1()` works (returns `"hello!"`) while `call2()` panics with `reflect: Call using interface {} as type string`.

In the code below, the only difference between `call1()` and `call2()` is how `inValue` is created and initialized. I can **see clearly** why `call1()` results in `inValue` being a `string`, while `call2()` results in `inValue` being an `interface`, so my question is not so much as to why my code produces this, but rather:

Why can't Go perform the function call in the second case? I thought the interface still contains all the necessary information for calling the method successfully, given that `xCopy` is still really representing a string underneath. (Yes, I did already read the [laws of reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection))

I'll note that due to what I'm working on, I **do** need `inValue` to be settable within the function (hence the use of pointers).

Thanks!

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(call1(foo, "hello"))
    fmt.Println(call2(foo, "hello"))
}

func foo(x string) string {
    return x + "!"
}

func call1(f, x interface{}) interface{} {
    fValue := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    inValue := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(x)).Elem()
    inValue.Set(reflect.ValueOf(x))

    inValue.Set(fValue.Call([]reflect.Value{inValue})[0])

    return inValue.Interface()
}

func call2(f, x interface{}) interface{} {
    fValue := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    xCopy := x
    inValue := reflect.ValueOf(&xCopy).Elem()

    inValue.Set(fValue.Call([]reflect.Value{inValue})[0])

    return inValue.Interface()
}
```

**Edit**

Perhaps the question then becomes: Why doesn't Go assign the real type, rather than `interface`, for `inValue := reflect.ValueOf(&xCopy).Elem()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panic message explains the problem. The value in `reflect.ValueOf(&xCopy)` has type `*interface{}`.  The `Elem()` of this value has type `interface{}`.  The function argument is of type `string`.  An `interface{}` value is not a `string` value, even when the `interface{}` contains a `string`.

Note that the address of an interface value is a pointer to the interface, not a pointer to the value in the interface.

Comment: True, though `inValue` would not be settable. I forgot to mention that in my requirements. Updated the question.

Comment: @menehune23 It's not clear what you are asking given the code provided in the question. Update the question to demonstrate how you might use the settable value.  In any case, I answered the question as posed.

Comment: Yep, it's updated now. Though I would argue you didn't truly answer my question. I'm not really asking how to fix it (since `call1()` works perfectly well). I'm asking a deeper question if anyone knows why Go cannot perform the call.  "so my question is not so much as to why my code produces this -- my real question is:

Why can't Go perform the function call in the second case?" I ask because `xCopy` is still a string underneath.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just being overly assuming of what reflection is capable of...

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer explains why call2 does not work. I'll delete the code to make it clearer.

Comment: I understand that part already. I know that "The value in `reflect.ValueOf(&xCopy)` has type `*interface{}`". But why? If the interface contains both the type and value information, why doesn't Go use those when calling `ValueOf()` on an interface (or interface pointer)?

Comment: The address of an interface value is a pointer to the interface, not a pointer to the value in the interface.